# Android: Layout Help Create as in Image

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create a sign-in screen like this, am using Android studio.
[Screen design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Ilz.png).

How do I do this?

The lock and user icon is available here: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g36a32a9fc3a1ae3a99959004714c5d27f473d16f6

This is as far as I've created. I need to know how to give the colors as in the picture. I'm trying it, but it isn't working as expected. Also I need the background color not to merge with the EditText.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Login"
android:id="@+id/">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp" />


<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/nameET"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/passwordET"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameET"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nameET"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/nameET"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="LOGIN >"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/passwordET"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passwordET"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/passwordET"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/passwordET"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/passwordET"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:ellipsize="end" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Forgot Password"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxWidth="35dp"
    android:maxHeight="36dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:src="@drawable/useri"
    android:background="#ff4066ff"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/nameET"
    android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxWidth="35dp"
    android:maxHeight="36dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:src="@drawable/locki"
    android:background="#ff4066ff"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/passwordET"
    android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="EGO >"
    android:id="@+id/egoTV"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/nameET"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="40dp"/>
```

Comment: Am stuck at the point of adding the user and lock images, and my current sign-in screen looks like this:
http://i.imgur.com/LSZ3nXS.png

Answer (score 0):

The best way start from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html).
Try to understand how work android UI.
In your project find res folder.
In that folder you can find `main_activity.xml` file or something like this 
You can create your own UI in editor or using XML.

Comment: Hi there, this is as far as I've created. I've edited my main post. Is it possible to help now?

Answer (score 0):

This layout is rather complex and if you create too many views, it might be very inefficient. Here is my take on this. For the "Ego" logo, create a single `TextView` and set the `android:drawableRight` to the arrow drawable you wanna use, also if you want some space between the "EGO" text and the arrow drawable, set the `android:drawablePadding` to the value you prefer. For the container of the 3 form controls, group them in a `LinearLayout` and  create a 9-patch drawable and don't specify the stretchable area for the pointing-upwards arrow because when the drawable stretches, the arrow will stay the same which is what you want, you don't want it to stretch to look ugly, use padding to offset those views the way you want, and set the `android:background` to the stretchable 9-patch image you created. For the username and password fields, you could use the `EditText` view and also set the `android:drawableLeft` to the icons you have, you may also create custom background using the `ShapeDrawable` in XML. For the login button, it is the simplest to implement, create a button of course, but you need to create a new  `ShapeDrawable` resource and use the `radius` element as a child of the `shape` root element to make the rounded corner like that, the arrow in the button you could use the greater sign on your keyboard or create an image using Inkscape which is free, very powerful application you should check out if you haven't yet, and also use the `android:drawableRight` attribute. Alright, last piece is just a `TextView` with the attribute `android:textStyle` set to `italic`. That is how I would do it, it is lots of work, but it is a little work, but you will end up with a layout that is a little more efficient (you could eliminate the use of `ImageView` if you followed my suggestion). Hope you find this helpful.

You use these attributes to create a shadow effect `android:shadowDx` `android:shadowDy` `android:shadowColor` `android:shadowRadius`. Dx and Dy are for the horizontal and vertical offset, positive values offset the shadows to right and down respectively, you could even use negative values in which case the shadows go the opposite directions. The radius attribute is for how blurred you want the shadow to be, and color is self-explanatory, but my favorite colors are #d9d9d9 and #550(or #555500) and, but use the #xxx is more memory efficient if any color components have the same value like #55 55 00,  I just use #550.

Comment: Also, You don't come here and demand people to do stuff for you, you just come here to get help when you are baffled by a question or get an error you coudn't figure out, just a heads-up. Don't take it personally when someone corrects you though. Have a good day. Oh by the way, I am just a beginner too, but a very very motivated and determined one.

Comment: Thank you very much and one more question. http://i.imgur.com/mjYpZxQ.png    . How can I create that shade at the front of each EditText box?